# Rails add 2nd show view

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I would like to have a 2nd show file for a table called locations.
The file is views/locations/show2.html.erb

I've already added a 2nd index called index2.html.erb and I access it through

```
 locations_index2_path
```

- and I have a route called   get "locations/index2"

But, if I try something similar, it doesn't work:

```
location_show2_path(location)
```

I've also added this to the location controller:

```
def show2
  @location = Location.find(params[:id])
end
```

Thanks!

UPDATE - I'm getting "Couldn't find Location without an ID"
Parameters:

```
{"format"=>"14"}
```

URL:

```
http://localhost:5000/locations/show2.14
```

Routes:

```
  get "locations/show2"
```

Locations Controller:

```
 def show2
  @location = Location.find(params[:id])

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # show2.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @location }
  end
end
```

Link in index view:

```
          <%= link_to 'Show', locations_show2_path(location),  :class => 'btn btn-mini btn-success' %>
```

Comment: Did you add the route to your show2?

Comment: Still getting an error - I updated my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This new error means you are not passing an `params[:id]` to your action on your controller. You can do this by adding information on your link:

```
 <%= link_to 'Show', locations_show2_path(:id => location.id) %>
```

As `show2` is a custom route, you have to specify what is the name of the parameter you are passing to the controller. Hope it helps.